# File upload form, attach a file condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file upload form with jquery validator to check a file size. Validator fires, I have a proper IF statement, but how to prevent a file from being attached? I thought return would do the trick, but a file is 'attached' to the upload button anyways (a file name appears next to it).

```
 $('#fileUploadButton').on('change', function() {
        var fileSizeInBytes = this.files[0].size;
        if(fileSizeInBytes>512000){
            alert("this file is to big!");
            return;
        }else{
            //generate preview
        }
  });
```

Comment: `change` events fire _after_ the change has occurred. The user has already selected the file (otherwise you could not read its size in the first place), you can not “cancel” it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below mentioned solution.

```
$('#fileUploadButton').on('change', function() {
        var fileSizeInBytes = this.files[0].size;
        if(fileSizeInBytes>512000){
            alert("this file is to big!");
            // Reset file input
            $('input[type="file"]').val(''); 
            // OR
            $('#input_file_id').val('');   
            return;
        }else{
            //generate preview
        }
  });
```

Comment: this will reset the whole form, won't it? Not only file input

Comment: So you want to reset only reset file input..?

Comment: This will not only reset the whole form, it will reset *every* form in the document

Comment: Please check my updated answer, Change `input_file_id` with your input ID

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).val('');` or `this.value = ''`. It will clear the selected value for file input.

```js
$('#fileUploadButton').on('change', function(e) {
        var fileSizeInBytes = this.files[0].size;
        if(fileSizeInBytes>100){
            alert("this file is to big!");
            $(this).val(''); //or this.value = '';
            return;
        }else{
            //generate preview
        }
  });
```

```html
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <input type="file" id="fileUploadButton" />
```

Change file size as per requirement. I have added 100 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the file input's value:

```
$('#fileUploadButton').on('change', function() {
    var fileSizeInBytes = this.files[0].size;
    if (fileSizeInBytes > 512000){
        alert("this file is to big!");
        $(this).val('');

        return;
    } else {
        //generate preview
    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

And a bit of pure js way to do this:

```
$('#fileUploadButton').on('change', function() {
        var fileSizeInBytes = this.files[0].size;
        if(fileSizeInBytes>512000){
            alert("this file is to big!");
            //pure js input reset
            document.getElementById(this.id).value = ''; 
            return;
        }else{
            //generate preview
        }
  });
```

[Here is js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emmp02pf/)